# Generating permutation array without replacement

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, permutation, sample

I am trying to get a matrix of size `(1000, 7)` in which each row is a random permutation of the numbers 0 to 6.
I am using the following code to implement the requirement.

```
import numpy as np

permute_array = []
for i in range(1000):
    permute_array.append(np.random.permutation(7))
permute_array = np.array(permute_array)
```

This is slow as the for loop takes quite some time to run. Is there a one shot way of generating this array? Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be random? And does each have to be different or can they be all the same?

Comment: @Tom each row is a random sample of the integers from 0 to 6. Ideally each row needs to be different from the other rows, until all the possibilities are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
permute_array = np.argsort(np.random.rand(1000, 7), axis=1)
```

Comment: Wow, never thought of it this way. Cool answer

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do so,
if you just need a solution for this case (this function) you can just create array (1000,7) fill it with range(7) and then shuffle each row using `np.apply_along_axis`:

(Not recommended for an abstract solution but it's really fast)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.full((1000, 7),fill_value=np.arange(7))
np.apply_along_axis(func1d=np.random.shuffle, axis=1, arr=a)
print(a[:5])
```

performance: 2.96 ms ± 21.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Another elegant and also fast and more abstract solution is to use your permutation function:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([np.random.permutation(7) for i in range(1000)])
print(a[:5])
```

performance: 2.13 ms ± 30.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

The second solution looks a bit faster.

Comment: So the one with python loop is faster! Btw, how are you saying there is no statistically significant difference?

Comment: About the first question, this type of `for` loops is optimized in C level and very efficient.
Regarding second question you are right, it is, I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `itertools.permutations` to generate all the permutations (5040 in your case) and then use something like `random.choices` to select 1000 permutations at random.
It would avoid to have two identical rows, which your code can't. Don't know if it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array from zeros and then replace it with permutation, with apply_along_axis from np which is very fast.

```
import itertools

np.apply_along_axis(lambda _: list(itertools.permutations(range(7))), 0, np.zeros(1000))
```

Comment: It would be better if you compare the execution time of your method with the other methods proposed here. So that in the future if somebody comes looking here, they'll directly know which one's better.